# How to document json/yaml schema in restructured text

Tags: json, yaml, openapi, restructuredtext, redocly

I would like to include json schema or yaml openapi or component/model object in restructured text. After a bit of googling i came across [sphinx-jsonschema](https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-jsonschema/) extension. But unfortunately the large table created is not very readable as my schmea is very big both in length and breadth wise.

I know that readocly and swagger generates beautiful documentation with nice drop down menu for whole openapi document with all rest end points. But in my case I would like to generate html page for single model object, for example

sample.json

```
{
    "$id": "https://example.com/person.schema.json",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "Person",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "subType1": {
        "type": "object",
        "description": "A sub type with additionalProperties false.",
        "properties": {
          "subProp1": {
            "type": "number"
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      },
      "subType2": {
        "type": "object",
        "description": "A sub type with additionalProperties true.",
        "properties": {
          "subProp2": {
            "type": "number"
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": true
      },
      "anInt": {
        "type": "integer",
        "description": "This is an integer, it should not show additional properties. (issue #132)"
      }
    },
    "additionalProperties": {
      "type": "object",
      "description": "additionalProperties schema.",
      "properties": {
        "propA": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Looking for better documentation for a single json/yaml object in restructures text.

Thanks

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/sphinxcontrib-redoc/ -- https://pypi.org/project/sphinxcontrib-openapi/

Comment: @sinoroc I have tried them. They suit to document openapi.yaml. But I would like to document json schema